# How to Align vanity flush without creating a gap from baseboard?

Tags: flooring, baseboard

We are installing this vanity and we are trying to figure out our best situation the legs are flush against the back of the vanity so the whole unit will be fat on the wall. But with the baseboard installed the vanity will sit off the wall leaving a good size gap along the back of the sink and the backsplash tile won’t fill that gap. What is the best solution for this?

[image]

[image]

You can see the gap that would happen.

[image]

Comment: Install baseboard  after the vanity is set

Comment: Install vanity after floor is finished.

Comment: Stop the baseboard where the legs of the vanity is at the proper placement.  From the photo, you may have to shim a bit under the front  leg to bring the back of the vanity flat against the wall.  The vanity top may slope toward the back.  It's a compromise between how level you want the top and how flat against the wall you want, with how much gap can be at the top back slash.  Does this have a sink installed in the top???

Answer (score 2):

You either cut the back bottom of the vanity to clear the baseboard, or the baseboard to clear the vanity - in this case, with "legs" rather than cabinet sides, (so small rather than large support for the base) cutting the baseboard seems like the obvious choice. *With plywood cabinets that reach the floor and sit on it full-length, coping out for the baseboard would have no significant effect on the structure.*

Third possibility would be to return the vanity and get one with legs positioned differently, but that may not be practical.

Either the wall or the back of the vanity is not plumb, evidently, based on the first picture with no baseboard.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of a baseboard there...   I agree otherwise - for this type of vanity we notch the baseboard which would be a PITA.

Comment: @DMoore I think neither the baseboard nor final flooring have been installed yet